# Eclipse Mars how to find path for Maven to be configured in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, osx-elcapitan

Installed Eclipse Mars which comes with Maven. Trying to setup Maven home on Jenkins but cannot find the maven home path Mac OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Mars include Maven as a plugin. You have to Download Maven and install it to have your `./m2`.

Also you have to declare it in your environment variables to detect it.